# Tomcat 8.5.9 multiple subdomains

Tags: java, tomcat, subdomain

I am trying to set up multiple subdomains on Tomcat 8.5.9 but I cannot get the syntax correct in the server.xml to get it to work.  I'm sure it's something I am missing on my end but none of the write ups I have found give the full explanation without also using Apache.  I am not using Apache or NGINX here.  I just want to set up a DEV server with multiple subdomains hosted on the same JVM.

test.foo.com

test1.foo.com

DNS is set up correctly and an nslookup to each URL gives the same public IP address.

The applications are deployed to the "test" and "test1" directories off of "webapps".

The way this is set up the test1.foo.com URL works but the test.foo.com URL is getting 404 errors when I hit it. Errors are being written to the log so it is coming up.

These are my host entries from server.xml:

```
  <Host name="test.foo.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context docBase="test" path=""/>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="test_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>

  <Host name="test1.foo.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

    <Context docBase="test1" path=""/>

    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="author_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

  </Host>
```

If anybody can see any errors I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Could you try with a diferent directory for each virtual host in `appBase`? The documentation does not prevent using the same directory for two virtual hosts, but all examples always use different directory

Comment: That did it.  I changed one of the WAR file locations to a different appBase and presto, it worked.  Thanks so much for the comment.  I was really spinning my wheels there.

Comment: Ok, I think it is interesting for future use. I'll post as answer

Answer (score 0):

(solved in comments)

Set a diferent directory for each virtual host in `appBase`. The [general documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/host.html) does not stablish restrictions, but  the specific [documentation for virtual host](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) says you can not use the same directory for two virtual hosts

> Note that the directory structures under the appBase for each host should not overlap each other.